# Weird surface thing

Tags: filament, 3d-models, extrusion, slic3r, surface

I have a 3D printer at home, the Colido Compact, and for some reason when I 3D print big flat surfaces a really weird thing happens. I'm using some PLA from Colido too I think

[image: Weeeird surface artefacts]

It almost seems as if the bottom layer does perfectly but when it starts printing out the top surface this happens, because the one on the bottom left is in two parts because the upper part is the bottom one and that one is perfectly flat, then I took them apart and the weird thing just stayed with the top part... and also on the weird warps there are bits of brown goo or something? I don't know it looks as if the filament was burned...
It only appears on pretty big surfaces because smaller ones don't seem to have the problem.

Anyone knows what is happening?

Comment: I mean, how many layers do you print for horizontal surfaces.

Comment: I dont know i just get a model, slice it with options: Support, Cooling, Layer Height, Infill Density, Infill Pattern and Solid Infill Pattern... i have a really simplified slicer for beginners

Comment: Trough a modified version of slic3r for the Print-Rite Colido Repetier-Host

Comment: But i also have a modified cura slicer but i dont use that

Comment: If the left bottom part is printed like displayed, your first layer is far from OK.

Answer (score 1):

If you hear some "clicking" during the print then you are experiencing filament slipping inside the extruder gear.
I had a similar issue on my Geeetech i3 and I fixed it by replacing the extruder tooth gear, the one that pushes the filament inside the hot-end.
Also, I advice to double check your filament is not getting stuck and your Spool spins freely.

Comment: Ill check on that, i never actually saw it in action

Answer (score 1):

**It could be over extrusion.**

Since I do not have physical access to your prints I cannot make sure. Please check if the thickness of the part is actually higher than what it supposed to be. Also, check the printing process during the print. Is the object taller than the nozzle at any time?

I generally have the same problem at the first layer, as sometimes I squeeze the first layer too much, causing extreme over extrusion. But unlike your case, upper layers kind of fixes the issue. In your case, the issue is amplified as you get higher. Walls turn out to be ok as there is room for flament to grow around, it is the flat surfaces that will got hit bad.

I strongly suggest you to print calibration pieces to ensure correct setting. If you have caliper you could try [this](https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:2490893) or if you don't [this](https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:14630) one might help.